# How to run CTS tests in android(Eclair)?

Tags: android, testing

In order to release a device to the market, You need to run the Compatibility Test Suite given by android...I need to know how to download and run it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As XC said in a comment, as of 2.0, the CTS is freely available.

For it to be runnable, you have to build the tests.
In your top level android directory, do all the normal build set-up steps and then

```
make cts
```

Then in the `out/host/linux-x86/cts/android-cts/tools` sub directory, you will find the `startcts` bash script. I expect the location might depend on what platform you are building on. Modify it to point out your SDK and then run the script. It is relatively self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the guides and links above that helps me to setup the CTS successfully.

I using
- Android CTS v2.3_r8

I summarize the steps here for those who wish to get CTS up on Windows.

1. Install cygwin here: http://www.cygwin.com
2. I placed `android-cts` in my `cygwin` folder e.g. `C:\cygwin\home\Username\`. You may set up  accordingly if you have placed it elsewhere.
3. Create new Environment Variables to point to SDK_ROOT and CTS_ROOT directories

   1. Go to Control panel->System -> Advanced tab
   2. Click on Environment variables
   3. Click on New to add CTS_ROOTS to system variables and add the path of android-cts to its value
   4. Do the same for SDK_ROOT and add the path of andriod-sdk to its value
4. Go to `android-cts\tools` and modify 2 lines in the `startcts` script file as follows [With help from How to run Android's CTS on windows on an emulator but some slight modification that works for me

   ```
   JARS="$(cygpath -w -p ${CTS_LIB}:${DDM_LIB}:${JUNIT_LIB}:${HOSTTEST_LIB})"
   java ${JAVA_OPTS} -cp ${JARS} com.android.cts.TestHost "$(cygpath -w "${CONFIG}")" "$@" ${DDCONFIG}
   ```

Save `startcts` as Unix file. I use `dos2unix.exe` downloaded from http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html to convert it to Unix file.

Then, to run CTS

1. Attach android device to PC
2. (a) Go to cmd prompt, type  `adb install -r android-cts/repository/testcases/CtsDeviceAdmin.apk`
3. (b) On the device, enable all the `android.deviceadmin.cts.*` device administrators under Settings > Location & security > Select device administrators
4. Run cygwin and go to `android-cts/tools`
5. Execute Android CTS by `./startcts`

For how to run the tests in CTS, I refer again to section Working with CTS
 in the link given the earlier comment by cezio
"using-androids-compatibility-test-suite"

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite good documentation on Android's source website. Also, some time ago I've wrote [small crash course on CTS](http://bitbar.com/blog/44/using-androids-compatibility-test-suite).

Answer (score 1):

As of ICS (4.0), cts has had a bit of a makeover. Now it's called `cts-tradefed`.

The Google-provided documentation is available [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cts-manual-r4.pdf&ei=q6eMT4DHE7OD0QG9peHtCQ&usg=AFQjCNHjaBeKf6ak3qxFkhc2X_Rli-Cb6Q).

For a simple way to get up to speed on using cts-tradefed from your AOSP root directory and a connected device with a matching AOSP build:

```
make cts
cd out/host/$OSDIR/cts/android-cts/tools
./cts-tradefed
```

Here, `$OSDIR` is either `linux-x86`, `darwin-x86`

in the cts-shell:

```
help
list packages
list plans
run cts --plan CTS
run cts --package android.webkit
```

If it's not obvious, you can also use one of the plans or packages listed from `list packages` or `list plans`. 
Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else. It would've been quite helpful for me to find it earlier.