# Android CTS : downloading of CTS, environment setup, building and execution

Tags: android, android-source

If you know about Compatibility Test Suit for Android. Please send us the information regarding source code downloading of CTS, environment setup, building and execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the info about [setting up and running CTS](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cts-manual-r4.pdf) here.

If you are in a hurry,here are the commands you use most often:
Running CTS:

First, add the `android-sdk-linux/platform-tools` to the PATH using `export PATH=$PATH:/your-path-goes-here`

1- Navigate to the platform-tools directory and use
      `./android-cts/tools/startcts` to start the CTS shell

2- `run cts --plan CTS` to initiate CTS

3- (OPTIONAL) `ls --plan CTS`  to list all the individual test packages

4a- In case you want to run the entire test suite/plan:
    `start --plan CTS`

4b- In case you want to run the test for a single package:
    `start --plan CTS -p package-name-goes-here`

Answer (score 1):

1. Download source code of CTS:

   It's now available. You can just **repo sync** it, or **git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/cts.git**
2. Env Setup and build

   I also feel problems at building the cts. I build successfully once but other times I can't build it. You can see question [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824015/how-to-build-android-cts-and-how-to-add-and-run-your-test-case), I also record the step of my building.
3. Execution

   Since I didn't got the cts tool, I can only recommend you read [***this***](http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-add-test-plan-package-to-android.html), this is a 0xlad people's article.

Answer (score 0):

To download the CTS compilable code you follow the instructions out [here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.3_r1
```

If you work for some of the OEM's Google will provide special cts branches, if not, you'll have to do with the above branch.

To [build and run CTS](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-development.html) :

```
cd /path/to/android/root
./cts/development/ide/eclipse/genclasspath.sh > .classpath
chmod u+w .classpath

cd /path/to/android/root
make cts
cts
```

This answer obviously applies to 4.0.3 version of Android. Things may or may not change from Jelly Bean onwards.

Answer (score 0):

**Download cts source code :**

```
$ mkdir <dir_name>
$ cd <dir_name>
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b <tag_name> ( tag_name :-  android-cts-8.0_r2,  android-cts-7.1_r10)
$ repo sync -d -c –q
```

**Compile complete cts package:**

```
$ cd <dir_name>
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ make cts -j TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm64
```

**Compile particular cts :**

```
$  cd <dir_name>
$  . build/envsetup.sh
$  cd <testcase_dir_name>
$  mm
```

Answer (score -1):

CTS setup includes 3 steps

Step 1 : CTS Dowloads

Step 2 : Desktop Machine Setup

Step 3 : Android Device Configuration

**Step1 : Compatibility Test Suite Downloads**

i)Download and open the CTS packages matching your device’s Android version and all the Application Binary Interfaces (ABIs) your devices support from following link
https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/downloads.html
Then Unzip it and paste the android-cts to your workspace directory
ii)Download and open the latest version of the CTS Media Files.Unzip it and paste into your workspace directory

**Step 2 : Desktop Machine Setup:**

CTS currently supports 64-bit Linux and Mac OS host machines. CTS will not work on Windows OS.

i)Before running the CTS, make sure you have recent versions of both Android Debug Bridge (adb) and Android Asset Packaging Tool (AAPT) installed and those tools' location added to the system path of your machine.Ensure adb and aapt are in your system path

ii)set the path using the following command
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/ramakrishna/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3
where 27.0.3 is

iii)Install the proper version of the Java Development Kit (JDK). For Android 7.0—
On Ubuntu, use OpenJDK 8.
On Mac OS, use jdk 8u45 or newer.
For details, see the JDK requirements.

please follow below link for complete details of **Android Device configuration and Running CTS**

[Android CTS : downloading of CTS, environment setup, building and execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326246/does-android-cts-test-installed-apps-in-device/53392906#53392906)