# Does Android CTS test installed apps in device?

Tags: android, cts

I'm trying to execute the CTS but i can't.

So i just want to know if CTS check for installed apps or just the hardware components.

I used **CtsVerifier.apk**, but i don't know if this apk makes same test that pc commands

Answer (score -1):

**Andriod CTS Setup**

The CTS runs on a desktop machine and executes test cases directly on attached devices or an emulator.The CTS is an automated testing harness.

[image]

CTS setup includes 3 steps

**Step 1** : CTS Dowloads

**Step 2** : Desktop Machine Setup

**Step 3** : Android Device Configuration

**Step1 : Compatibility Test Suite Downloads**

i)Download and open the CTS packages matching your device’s Android version and all the Application Binary Interfaces (ABIs) your devices support from following link
https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/downloads.html
Then Unzip it and paste the android-cts to your workspace directory

ii)Download and open the latest version of the CTS Media Files.Unzip it and paste into your workspace directory

**Step 2 : Desktop Machine Setup:**

CTS currently supports 64-bit Linux and Mac OS host machines. CTS will not work on Windows OS.
i)Before running the CTS, make sure you have recent versions of both Android Debug Bridge (adb) and Android Asset Packaging Tool (AAPT) installed and those tools' location added to the system path of your machine.Ensure adb and aapt are in your system path

ii)set the path using the following command
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/ramakrishna/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3
where 27.0.3 is

iii)Install the proper version of the Java Development Kit (JDK). For Android 7.0—
On Ubuntu, use OpenJDK 8.
On Mac OS, use jdk 8u45 or newer.
For details, see the JDK requirements.

**Step 3 : Android Device Configuration:**

Screen and storage
i)Any device that does not have an embedded screen needs to be connected to a screen.

ii)If the device has a memory card slot, plug in an empty SD card. Use an SD card that supports Ultra High Speed (UHS) Bus with SDHC or SDXC capacity or one with at least speed class 10 or higher to ensure it can pass the CTS.
Warning: CTS may modify/erase data on the SD card plugged into the device.

iii)If the device has SIM card slots, plug in an activated SIM card to each slot. If the device supports SMS, each SIM card should have its own number field populated.

Factory data reset the device: Settings > Backup & reset > Factory data reset
Warning: This will erase all user data from the device.

1. Set your device's language to English (United States) from: **Settings > Language & input > Language**
2. Turn on the location setting if there is a GPS or Wi-Fi / Cellular network feature on the device: **Settings > Location > On**
3. Connect to a Wi-Fi network that supports IPv6, can treat the Device Under Test (DUT) as an isolated client (see the Physical Environment section above), and has an internet connection: **Settings > Wi-Fi**
4. Make sure no lock pattern or password is set on the device: **Settings > Security > Screen lock > None**
5. Enable USB debugging on your device: **Settings > Developer options > USB debugging.**

Note: On Android 4.2 and later, Developer options is hidden by default. To make them available, go to **Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times.** Return to the previous screen to find Developer options. See Enabling On-device Developer Options for additional details.

6. Make sure the time is set to 12-hour format: **Settings > Date & time > Use 24-hour format > Off**
7. Select: **Settings > Developer options > Stay Awake > On**
8. Select: **Settings > Developer options > Allow mock locations > On**
   Note: This mock locations setting is applicable only in Android 5.x and 4.4.x.
9. Select: **Settings > Developer options > Verify apps over USB > Off**
   Note: This verify apps step became required in Android 4.2.
10. Launch the browser and dismiss any **startup/setup screen.**
11. Connect the desktop machine that will be used to test the device with a **USB cable**

Note: When you connect a device running Android 4.2.2 or later to your computer, the system shows a dialog asking whether to accept an RSA key that allows debugging through this computer. Select Allow USB debugging.

12. Install and configure helper apps on the device.
    Note: For CTS versions 2.1 R2 through 4.2 R4, set up your device (or emulator) to run the accessibility tests with:

adb install -r android-cts/repository/testcases/CtsDelegatingAccessibilityService.apk
On the device, enable: Settings > Accessibility > Accessibility > Delegating Accessibility Service

Note: For CTS versions prior to 7.0, on devices that declare android.software.device_admin, set up your device to run the device administration test using:

adb install -r android-cts/repository/testcases/CtsDeviceAdmin.apk
In Settings > Security > Select device administrators, enable the twoandroid.deviceadmin.cts.CtsDeviceAdminReceiver* device administrators. Ensure theandroid.deviceadmin.cts.CtsDeviceAdminDeactivatedReceiver and any other preloaded device administrators remain disabled.

13. Copy the CTS media files to the device as follows:

Note: For CTS 2.3 R12 and later, if the device supports video codecs, the CTS media files must be copied to the device.
Navigate (cd) to the path the media files are downloaded and unzipped to.

Change the file permissions: chmod u+x copy_media.sh
Run copy_media.sh:

To copy clips up to a resolution of 720x480, run: **./copy_media.sh 720x480**
If you are not sure about the maximum resolution, try **./copy_media.sh all** so that all files are copied.

If there are multiple devices under adb, add the -s (serial) option to the end. For example, to copy up to 720x480 to the device with serial 1234567, run:**./copy_media.sh 720x480 -s 1234567**

please check the below link for **CTS setup**

https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/setup

**Run Andriod CTS**
To run a test plan:
1. Connect at least one device.

2. Press the **home button** to set the device to the home screen at the start of CTS.
3. While a device is running tests, it must not be used for any other tasks and must be kept in a stationary position (to avoid triggering sensor activity) with the cameras pointing at an object that could be focused.
4. **Do not press any keys** on the device while the CTS is running. Pressing keys or touching the screen of a test device will interfere with the running tests and may lead to test failures.
5. Launch the **CTS console** by running the cts-tradefed script from the folder where the CTS package has been unzipped, 
   e.g. **$ ./android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed**
6. Start the default test plan (contains all test packages) by appending:
   run cts --plan CTS.This kicks off all CTS tests required for compatibility.
   For CTS v1 (Android 6.0 and earlier), enter list plans to view a list of test plans in the repository or list packages to view a list of test packages in the repository.

For CTS v2 (Android 7.0 and later), enter list modules to see a list of test modules.

7. Alternately, run the CTS plan of your choosing from the command line using: 
   cts-tradefed run cts --plan

Note: When running Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) CTS only, we recommend you use the --skip-preconditions option to skip the experimental pre-conditions feature that may cause issues for when executing CTS tests.

8. View test progress and results reported on the console.
9. If your device is Android 5.0 or later and declares support for an ARM and a x86 ABI, you should run both the ARM and x86 CTS packages.

For Android 6.0 or earlier, you'll use CTS v1.

For Android 7.0 or later, you'll use CTS v2.

To Run the default CTS plan (that is, the full CTS invocation) run the following command.--disable-reboot must be included in the command

**cts-tf>run cts --disable-reboot**

Note :While running Android CTS some times Android CTS stops its execution,We can resume its execution from where it is stopped using following steps
Step 1:Check the details of the session in the CTS console by running following command

**cts-tf>list results** 
[image]

you need to specify the latest session after --retry
cts-tf>run cts --retry 3 --disable-reboot
Please check the following for full details of Android CTS Run,CTS v1 and CTS v2
https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/run

It will take more time to complete,be patient,once completed you can check test details in the directories **logs** and **results**  under **android-cts** directory

Comment: Please consider adding useful information related to the question