# Starting CTS from the commandline

Tags: android, android-cts

How do I start the Android CTS from the command line, I have tried every combination that I can think of:

```
~/programs/android-cts/tools$ ./startcts --config ../repository/host_config.xml start -plan CTS
```

and the like does not work. Any input will be very much appreciated?

Comment: Running CTS has changed since the release of ICS. You should check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10183036/198348

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is just a matter of reading the CTS source code, and then getting the parameters correct: :)

```
$ ./startcts start --plan CTS
```

Comment: This doesn't work with recent versions of Android. There is a 'cts-tradefed' script instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have been using CTS version CTS4.4R3.
Below is how we can run CTS on KK .
Go to "tools" folder in CTS4.4R3 and enter the below commands : 
command to Run CTS :
.../tools$./cts-tradefed
>run cts --plan CTS

Creating a Plan for Failed Cases in the 1st run:
add derivedplan -p "anyName"-s <SessionID> -r fail
Run added Plan : run cts --plan <PlanName> 

SessionID can be checked as : list results

Running individual class in CTS :
run cts -c <ClassName>
run cts -c com.android.cts.monkey.android.widget.cts.AutoCompleteTextViewTest
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers understand this answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command startcts in the tools folder

```
<install_dir>/tools$./startcts
```

cts shell will show up, Choose the plan you want to run  as shown below

```
cts_host > ls --plan
List of plans (10 in total):
Android
AppSecurity
CTS-TF
CTS
Java
Performance
RefApp
Signature
VM-TF
VM

cts_host > start --plan Android
```

Comment: We need to script it, so I need cts to run in non-interactive mode, i.e. from the command-line.