# Do we need to have 64 bits OS to run Android CTS and Monkey test for Android ICS version ?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, cts

Experts :

First of all, I would like to get help on following question:

1. Instruction of how to set up a Google CTS on ICS ? ( which Ubuntu version I should use )
2. Do we need a 64 bit OS to run ICS CTS?
3. Does it matter to run monkey test on 32 bit Machine.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Both me and @knmanish have pretty decent answers to document on using CTS on ICS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10183036/198348

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073453/198348